# How can I make all factory girl factories available before evaluating them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

**Set up:**

We keep each factory in a separate file, and group them in directories to match our models directory structure. We also use mongo and many of our relations are `embeded_in` rather than typical `has_many` or `belongs_to`.

**Problem:**

When a factory needs to reference another one that is later in alpha order, factory girl throws  a `Factory not registered` error.

**Example:**

```
# spec/factories/cat.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cat do
    name 'fluffy'
    kittens [FactoryGirl.build(:kitten), FactoryGirl.build(:kitten)]
  end
end

# spec/factories/kitten.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :kitten do
    name 'mittens'
    age_in_months 2
  end
end
```

Since the `cat` factory is loaded before the `kitten` factory girl throws the `Factory not registered` error.

**Question**

How can I force factory girl to run through all the files and only check the name of the factory the file defines without caring what other factories it depends on?

Yes, I understand I could put the `kitten` factory in the same file as the `cat` factory, I also know I could rename `kitten.rb` to `a_kitten.rb` to get around this problem. I'd rather not do either of those. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
# spec/factories/cat.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cat do
    name 'fluffy'
    kittens { [build(:kitten), build(:kitten)] }
  end
end
```

Passing a block rather than a value makes it evaluate lazily.

Comment: The documentation for lazy attributes is here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Lazy_Attributes

Comment: Awesome! Works as advertised and thanks to @LeonardGarvey for the link to the docs :)